# How do I properly describe the application of a rotation matrix to a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

Basically, I have my terminology and notation all mixed up and I was hoping you could help me out.

I know that if I take any function, $g(x, y) = 0$ and I substitute $x,y$ according to $x_{old} = x_{new}cos \theta + y_{new} sin \theta$, and $y_{old} = -x_{new}sin \theta + y_{new}cos \theta$, the resulting equation will plot a rotation of the original function by $\theta$, $g(x_{new}cos \theta + y_{new} sin \theta, -x_{new}sin \theta + y_{new}cos \theta) = 0$.

The idea of doing this comes from applying the rotation matrix $R$ to the vector $\vec v$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} cos \theta & -sin \theta \\ sin \theta &cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$

Which is matrix-vector multiplication.

But I have my terminology and notation mixed up.

First, both $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, and given that there are no vectors, I'm lead to say that $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Or, is this incorrect, and given that there are two variables, even if there are no vectors, one should define $g$ as $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Second, in the procedure through which $g(x, y) = 0$ becomes $g(x_{new}cos \theta + y_{new} sin \theta, -x_{new}sin \theta + y_{new}cos \theta) = 0$, is it proper to say that we are applying $R$ to $g$? But this seems to me incorrect, since $g$ wasn't defined on a vector space, but matrices are, but isn't this supposed to be correct if we defined $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Thank you in advance, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Looks to me like you are *composing* $g$ and $R$ to form $g \circ R$ (where by abuse of notation I'm reusing the same letter $R$ to refer to the map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ induced by the matrix $R$). In any case, if $g(x,y)$ is a real-valued scalar, then $g$ is mapping $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Bungo is it necessary to determine if $g(x, y)$ is a real-valued scalar if I'm only interested by its properties as a curve when $g(x,y)=0$? thanks, by the way

Comment: (1) Your claim "there are no vectors" is clearly false, since $(x,y)$ is a vector. (2) Yes, you can say you are applying $R$ to $g$. Even though $R$ was originally defined to be applied to a vector space, it can still be used elsewhere.

Comment: @runway44 Thanks. Does that mean that it would be proper notation, without further explanation, to say $g(x, y) = g( \vec v)$, and $Rg = g(xcos \theta + ysin \theta, -xsin \theta + ycos \theta)$?

Comment: @Bungo and, if understood you correctly, did you mean the map $R$ is distinct from the matrix $R$?

Comment: Yes, you can define $Rg:=g\circ R^{-1}$ (not $g\circ R$ as Bungo said; you want that inverse there so that $(RS)g=R(Sg)$ is a true statement).

Comment: @runway44 thank you!

Comment: @runway44 a final question, the counter-example vector you gave, is it by convention a 2x1 vector or a 1x2 vector? To know whether or not to transpose it on matrix-vector multiplication, when using it as an input to $g$.

Comment: I mean, that's up to you.

Comment: @runway44 thank you again! I'm self-studying so that explains this sort of question hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will clarify what some of the comments described. Consider a function $f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$. Assuming the inputs are real numbers, and the output is a real number, then we can say that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. This is because the function has $n$ real numbers as inputs and a real number as output.

Now, consider $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]^T$ where the elements of $\mathbf{x}$ are a real numbers, which can be denoted by $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then, instead of writing, $f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, we may write $f(\mathbf{x})$. This is equivalent to the previous notation, and in both cases, the function $f$ has $n$ real numbers as input and a real number as output.

Therefore, if you are considering $g(x,y)$, then you have $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ assuming the inputs are real numbers, and the output is also a real number. The function $g$ is not concerned with the inputs meaning $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as long as you input real numbers. Thus, if you want to apply a rotation to the vector $[x,y]^T$, then you can write in several ways such as $g(R\mathbf{v})$ where $\mathbf{v} = [x,y]^T$, but other ways exist as well.

However, you are applying the rotation to the inputs not the function itself; thus, you cannot multiple the function by the rotation matrix. In other words, $g(R\mathbf{v}) \neq Rg(\mathbf{v})$, and furthermore, $Rg(\mathbf{v})$ doesn't actually make sense because $g$ outputs a scalar, and you can't multiple a scalar by a rotation matrix (assuming $R$ isn't a $1 \times 1$ matrix).

Comment: thank you! Although $Rg(\mathbf{v})$ doesn't work as a matrix multiplication, if we take it as a linear map, $(g \circ R)(\mathbf{v})$ does make sense however, no?

Comment: @shintuku I suppose you could say $(g \circ R)(\mathbf{v})$, but the notation seems odd to me (maybe not others) because typically the composition of functions is written with functions. For example, I would expect to see the composition written as $(g \circ h)(\mathbf{v})$ where $h(\mathbf{v}) = R \mathbf{v}$, but perhaps, this is my opinion. I just haven't seen something like $(g \circ R)(\mathbf{v})$ where $R$ is a matrix in my experience.